# How to take source for a revision in GitHub

Tags: github, repository

I am using BitBucket a GitHub repository, i would like to know how to get the Source of a particular revision?

I had committed some changes few days back, i want the entire source code for that revision, how can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

Using Git, using [git revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), supposing your revision was published on `master` branch:

```
cd C:\Temp
git clone https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/repoowner/projectname
git checkout master@{2 days ago}
```

(not kidding, you can specify a date specification like that!)

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket is a Mercurial/Git repository, a GitHub competitor.

If you want to retrieve a specific changeset/revision, you can use either Git or Mercurial.

Using mercurial:

```
cd C:\Temp
hg clone https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/repoowner/projectname
hg up -r revnumber
```

Where `revnumber` is the number of the revision you want to retrieve.